# If a function g is continuous and increasing, then there is a closed and unbounded set of p, such that g(p) = p. How to prove this?

Tags: set-theory

The problem essentially defines continuity and increasing functions in the following way:

Increasing: for any $a<b$, $g(a)<g(b)$

Continuous: $g(\sup\{p_i\}) = \sup\{f(p_i)\}$ where $i$ is an element of some $q<k$ where $k$ is a regular cardinal over which function $g$'s domain and co-domain are defined (i.e. $g: k\to k$).

Where do I start? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Sketch:** Suppose that $\kappa>\omega$ is a regular cardinal and that $g:\kappa\to\kappa$ is increasing and continuous. let $F=\{\alpha\in\kappa:g(\alpha)=\alpha\}$. First show that $F$ is closed in $\kappa$ by showing that if $\alpha\in\kappa$ is a limit point of $F$, then $\alpha\in F$; this is a completely straightforward consequence of the continuity of $g$.

To show that $F$ is unbounded, let $\alpha\in\kappa$ be arbitrary. The function $g$ is injective (why?), and $|\alpha|<\kappa$, so there must be an $\xi_0\in\kappa$ such that $g(\xi_0)\ge\alpha$. Now recursively construct a sequence $\langle\xi_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ such that $\xi_{n+1}>\max\{\xi_n,g(\xi_n)\}$ for each $n\in\omega$ and consider $g(\sup_n\xi_n)$. You will want the fact that $\xi\le g(\xi)$ for all $\xi\in\kappa$; this is easily proved by induction on $\xi$, using the fact that $g$ is increasing.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. But, I am still having trouble with showing that F is unbounded. What is the point of constructing the recursive sequence?

Comment: @user209069: Can you see why $\sup_n\xi_n=\sup_ng(\xi_n)$?

Comment: I'm not sure, is it because of the way F is defined?

Comment: @user209069: No, because of the way the $\xi_n$ are defined. You have $$\xi_0\le g(\xi_0)<xi_1\le g(\xi_1)\le\xi_2\le g(\xi_2)\le\ldots\,,$$ so the sequences of $\xi_n$ and $g(\xi_n)$ are interlaced. What does that say about their suprema? (You do need to know that $\xi\le g(\xi)$ for all $\xi\in\kappa$; this can be proved by induction, and I’m so used to it that I forgot to mention it. I’ll add that to the answer.)

Comment: I apologize if this is completely incorrect, but this means that the suprema of xi_n is xi_(n-1) and the supremum of g(xi_n) is g(xi_(n-1)). By definition, xi_(n-1) is less than or equal to g(xi_(n-1)).

Comment: @user209069: No, definitely not: the supremum of a set of things by definition is greater than or equal to all of them, because it’s their least upper bound. You want to show that $$\xi_0\le g(\xi_0)<\xi_1\le g(\xi_1)<\xi_2\le g(\xi_2)<\ldots$$ and then use that to show that $\sup_n\xi_n=\sup_ng(\xi_n)$. Then you can use continuity to show that you have an element of $F$ bigger than $\alpha$. Since $\alpha$ was arbitrary, this will show that $F$ is unbounded.

Comment: To the proposer: Let $Y$ be a Hausdorff space and let $X$ be any topological space. If $f:X: \to Y,\, g:X \to Y$ are continuous then $\{x \in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.... Continuity of $g:k \to k$ is equivalent to continuity with respect to the $ \in$-order topology, which is Hausdorff. So let $Y=X=k$ and $f=id_k.$ Then $ \{p: p=g(p)\} $ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question this?

Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal, and let $g:\kappa \to \kappa$ satisfy the following properties:

1. increasing, that is, if $a < b \in \kappa$, then $g(a) < g(b)$, and
2. continuous, that is, if $(p_i)_{i \in q}$ is a sequence in $\kappa$ for $ q \in \kappa$, then $g(\sup p_i) = \sup g(p_i) $.

Show there exists an unbounded $P \subset \kappa$ such that for all $a \in P$ we have $g(a) = a$.

Also, do you want the additional hypothesis that $\kappa$ is uncountable?  If $\kappa = \omega$, then $g(n) = n+1$ is a counterexample.

I guess you do it this way.  Show by induction that $a \le g(a)$ for all $a \in \kappa$.  Let $P = \{a \in \kappa : g(a) = a\}$.  Suppose for a contradiction that $P$ is bounded.  Then choose $u \in \kappa \setminus \sup(P)$.  Let $Q = \{g^k(u): k \in \omega\}$.  Let $p = \sup(Q)$.  Then $g(p) = p$, and $p \in \kappa \setminus \sup(P)$.

I forgot to show $P$ is closed, but as the other answer says, this follows immediately from the definitions.

To show $g(a)\ge a$ by induction:. it is clearly true for $a=0$.  Suppose it is true for all $b<a$.  If $a =b+1$ is a successor ordinal, see that $g(a)>g(b)\ge b$, hence $g(b)\ge b+1 = a$.  If $b$ is a limit ordinal, use property 2.

Comment: I understand your answer and the other answer, but I am just struggling to show the induction proof. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: I added to my answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you upvote our answers?